# Carousel on mobile device - three sections on devices above?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to have a bootstrap carousel with three text sections on a mobile device but on breakpoints higher have the text sections displayed as three sections in a horizontal row?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the carousel on large devices with `.d-md-none` and hide the row on mobile devices: `.d-none .d-md-block`

The disadvantage is that you will have to maintain the content in 2 places, but I think it's the cleanest solution, if you want to use bootstraps default components.

So something like this:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Row content for desktop here -->
   </div>
</div>

<div class="d-md-none">
   <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel content for mobile here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks so much guys! Great help!!